# Custom information policy : ComputeExpireDate() is not getting executed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a class which inherits `IExpirationFormula`,in which I have define ComputeExpireDate method which caluclate the expiry date of document.
The issue is that, this method is not getting executed .

Please help me out to know which event triggers this ComputeExpireDate(), so that I can debug it.

Comment: Have you created event receiver to add your ExpirationFormula? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-create-custom-expiration-formula-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: @Aanchal Yes I have. Even I am getting this custom formula in drop down list of Information Policy Management setting page.

Comment: You can try restarting your timer service and app pool recycle. Check if you  Expiration Policy and Information Management Policy job are runninh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. Its because VS2012 keeps on deploying old code. Resolved as
Tool--> Options -->Debugging -->General-->Require source file to exact match the origional version(I have unchecked it)